# Email Results from a query to all emails in the results

Tags: email, proc

I have what I thought was a simple question but havent been able to resolve it in months , so here it goes !!!

Environment :  Microsoft SQL 2008

I have a qyery that runs every night and gives me a list of all orders that dont have an approval code:

Query :

Select OrderId, First , Last ,Email from Orders where Approval is Null

Results:

### **OrderID   First         Last         Email**

4565       Tom          Cruise      Tom@email.com

3423       Jaime        Fox         jaime@email.com

Thats fine becuase now i know which orders dont have an approval but what i want to do is for the query to atomatcally email them something like

***Desired Result***
Dear Tom ,

Your order does not have an approval code and will be cancelled within the next 48 Hours if the code is not entered.

* Desired Result****

At any given time i may have 30 of these orderd so the query needs to just run and  generate an email to each person . if 1 person has multiple orders it is fine if they get an email for each order seperatly .    Please Help!! and by help I mean please let me see sample code to how to achieve this since i dont know how to.  Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the email capabilities in SQL Server for sending the emails.

Once you configure SQL Server ([follow this link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/)); you can simply go through each email in a loop, like so:

```
USE msdb
GO
EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='PinalProfile',
@recipients='tomcruise@Example.com',
@subject='Your Order',
@body='Hi there.'
```

**Update**

Here's an example of how to iterate through the records:

```
declare @temp as table
(
Id int identity,
OrderId int, 
First varchar(255), 
Last varchar(255),
Email varchar(512)

)

insert into @temp
Select OrderId, First , Last ,Email from Orders where Approval is Null

declare @email varchar(512)
       , @index int=1 
       , @upper_bound int
       , @subject varchar(500)

select @upper_bound=max(Id) from @temp


while(@index<=@upper_bound)
BEGIN
select @email=email,@subject='Your order number '+OrderID from @temp where Id=@index

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='profile',
@recipients=N@email,
@subject=@subject,
@body='Whatever you want to say here.'

select @index=@index+1

END

-- You are done
```

Comment: Thank you , I got this far before but thanks for the example anyways  , what i dont understand is how to do the loop, thanks ( I have sql server email setup already)